# How to build query and to make chart in Yii2 using highchart?

Tags: php, charts, yii, highcharts, yii2

I want to make chart from table in database. My database is on phpMyAdmin.
Here is my table:

**Table Hapus**

[image]

I want to make a chart like this in Yii2:

[image]

I have HighchartsController:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Hapus;
use yii\helpers\Json;


class HighchartsController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
    {

    $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Year'])
    ->from('hapus')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();

    $rowsa = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Female'])
    ->from('hapus')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();

    $rowsaa = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['Male'])
    ->from('hapus')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();

        $rows = [];
        $rowsa = [];
        $rowsaa= [];


        $data['year'] = json_encode($rows);
        $data['female'] = json_encode($rowsa);
        $data['male'] = json_encode($rowsaa);




        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }


}
```

this is my view index.php

```
<?php
use app\assets\HighchartsAsset;


HighchartsAsset::register($this);
$this->title = 'Highcharts Test';
?>


<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div id="my-chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



<?php $this->registerJs("
$(function () {
    $('#my-chart').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Gender',
            x: -20 //center
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: $year
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: $male
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: $female
        }]
    });
});
")?>
</div>
</div>
```

When I tried to run those codes, the chart didn't appear. It was like this:

[image]

There was no error in debug console. But, I don't know why the chart didn't appear

Could anyone please correct my codes? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: why you are repeating post the same question ????????

Comment: it's not the same question. There's no highchart code on my previous question and also there's no answer that I expect from that question @scaisEdge

Comment: Did you register highcharts.js library? Where is your html container #my-chart in your view? Check errors in debug js console..

Comment: yes I have registered highchart.js library. I also use html container in my view. The codes above is just a part of my codes @MarcinGordel

Comment: Are there any erros in js console?

Comment: there is no error. I have edited my question and I added the result picture. @MarcinGordel

Comment: I also have put full of codes on my question @MarcinGordel

Comment: Display source of results and check how data series are encoded to js. It should look like `data: [14, 76, 33, 45]`

Comment: I don't want to display the chart by typing the data's number, but I want to display the chart with query. @MarcinGordel

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, but you should debug how to result of queries (variable $female) is parsed to js script. You can do it by preview source of page results and find part of js code begin with `$('#my-chart').highcharts...` or otherwise 'var_dump($female)' in view.

Comment: I don't get it @MarcinGordel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an empty arrays before render view and also data in chart is empty:

```
$rows = [];
$rowsa = [];
$rowsaa= [];
```

And in query results you have wrong array structure.

Try this and use `column()` instead of `all()`:

```
class HighchartsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Year'])
            ->from('hapus')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $rowsa = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Female'])
            ->from('hapus')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $rowsaa = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Male'])
            ->from('hapus')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $rowsa = array_map('floatval', $rowsa);
        $rowsaa = array_map('floatval', $rowsaa);

        $data['year'] = json_encode($rows);
        $data['female'] = json_encode($rowsa);
        $data['male'] = json_encode($rowsaa);

        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }
}
```